Question about CDFs
Suppose that I have two arbitrary random variables $Y,X$ with strictly increasing CDF. Let $\omega(X)$ be a known function of $X$ that is known in advance and $\mu$ be a scalar parameter. Assume that the variables of the system satisfy:
$$ \mathbb{E}[Y \omega(X)] = \mu$$
I am interested in knowing whether we can produce a transformation of $X$ that mimics joint properties of $(Y,X)$. To be more concrete, let $F_Y(y)$ be the CDF of $Y$. Can we find a function $h(X)$ such that:
$$ \mathbb{P}(h(X) \le y) = F_Y(y), $$
$$ \mathbb{E}[h(X) \omega(X)] = \mu. $$
Intuitively, this says that $h(X)$ has the same CDF as $Y$ and produces the same weighted mean.
I thought of $h(X) = F_{Y \mid X}^{-1}(F_{X}(X))$, with the idea that $F_{X}(X)$ is uniformly distributed and that inverting the CDF gives the same distribution. I think this might satisfy the first constraint but not the second. Is this the right solution or is there a better approach? Does a solution exist at all?

The expectations are only over the distribution of $X$?

The three equations are defined over the joint distribution of (Y,X). The second and third equations only feature X as a random variable.

Incomplete: Let $X, Y$ be iid std uniform. Let $\omega=I(\cdot)$. $E[Y\omega(X)]=  \frac14$. (Note that $h(X)$ is independent of $Y$ here; I don't pursue this but it may help).
To begin with consider $h$ invertible $P(y\geq h(X))=P(h^{-1}(y)\geq X) = 1-F_X(h^{-1}(y))$. So we'd need $F_Y(y) = 1-F_X(h^{-1}(y))$, so $h(y)^{-1} = [F_X^{-1}(S_Y(y))]$. The quantile function of $X$ is the identity, so $h(y)^{-1} = (1-y)$, but $1-y$ is its own inverse. So $h(y) = 1-y$. $E[h(X)\omega(X)]=E[(1-X)X] = \frac16 \neq  \frac14$. I expect a more careful argument might rule out anything but decreasing h here

Short on time today; I post those thoughts in the hope that either I get some time to come back to this or that someone can generalize it.

$\mathbb{E}[Y \omega(X)] = \mu$ seems a strange thing to write if $\omega$ is a function of $Y$.  $X$ and $Y$ may have different supports.
